# Script for killing defunct process with parent 1

Tags: linux

I have a process who is a child of init (ppid = 1), something bad happened in my processes
and the process became zombie -

```
ps -ef | grep defunct
root     10384     1  0 Jun12 ?        00:48:22 [myProc] <defunct>
```

I tried killing it with kill -9 , pkill and killall nothing helps.
I tried sending SIGCHLD to its parent which is the init process but that does not help either.

Init is not reaping the process for some reason (probably a stuck I/O - bug in our code yet to be discovered)

It seems that the only way to get rid of this is to reboot the server, which is not
an acceptable solution.

How do I kill this process, or prevent this from happening in the future.

I **can** control the way I launch the process if this can prevent it from becoming defunct.

The process is obviously holding for resources which I need to use, hence leaving it to just hang there doesn't help.

Comment: Attaching a debugger or ``strace`` (via ``strace -p``) might reveal where the bug comes from, but this is out of scope for this question.

Comment: attaching the debugger to where? The process does not exist in linux in a manner that you can attach to it via gdb.

Comment: I also tried attaching to init with gdb and calling waitpid on my process but it never returned (well at least not for 30 seconds when my patience ran out)

Determine the zombie & parent processes' PIDS

Fire up gdb and attach to the parent:
attach 1
call waitpid(10384,0,0)
..

Comment: I assumed as it is stuck in a syscall, strace would be able to attach and determine which syscall it is. If this is not the case, I stand corrected. Does it have a procfs directory?

Comment: What strace command should I run to get that? I'm not sure it will have that info logged since a lot happened since the processes got stuck.

On the server there is only /proc directory not /procfs.

Under /proc/ the PID directory exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unpleasant answer is, you can’t. If the process is stuck in a syscall, it cannot be reaped in any way (otherwise, `init` would do it), at least not by software.

If the I/O is related to pluggable hardware, unplugging that hardware might terminate the syscall and thus the process can continue and/or terminate.

Comment: How can I tell which I/O is it stuck on? It might be an I/O through another process in our system...

Comment: In theory `lsof -p <pid of the zombie>` should do it. In my case I get a list of `fuse` mounts that tell 'lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system [...] Output information may be incomplete.' and I get no files. I assume that the fuse subsystem is to be blamed but the only fix seems to be to reboot the system unless I can interfere with the broken fuse mount.